# `lldb` gives random output on same function call

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, lldb

I'm trying to debug something using LLDB in Xcode 5.1

Here is the console log:

```
(lldb) call (double)tan(4)
(double) $1 = 3.2310333083476262E-296
(lldb) call (double)tan(4)
(double) $2 = 1.7383389519589487E-310
(lldb) call (double)tan(4)
(double) $3 = 2.2250738585072034E-308
(lldb) call (double)tanl(4)
(double) $5 = 0
(lldb) call (long double)tanl(4)
(long double) $6 = 6.26240511218997490612E-4941
(lldb) call (long double)tanl(4)
(long double) $7 = NaN
(lldb) call (long double)tanl(4)
(long double) $8 = 1.45807981275298984101E-4950
```

Why does tan behave as a random number generator ?

The results when I use the function are consistants in my program, it just appears wrong in `lldb`, I believe their is a type issue.

Comment: And none of those results are correct are they?

Comment: Nope, google tells us than tan(4) is 1.15782128235

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?

Comment: As said in question: 5.1

Comment: Ah yes, missed that :)  Looks like Martin R is correct tho.

Comment: I'm not sure about it... They say "When you wrote (lldb) p (double) sin(70.0) you fixed these mistakes." 
I understand that (double)tan(4) should give me an appropriate result right ?  Or is lldb always casting to int first ?

Comment: No, `p (double)tan(4.0)` would give the right result.

Comment: But it obviously doesn't in my log :(

Comment: @Antzi: What do you mean by "obviously"? I do not see the output of `p (double)tan(4.0)` in your log.

Comment: @MartinR So what does lldb output to me ? The call command should output the return value of tan(). Ex: `(lldb) call (int)strlen("toto")
(int) $0 = 4`

Comment: @Antzi: I don't think that I can explain it better than Jason Molenda did in the duplicate. - `p (double)tan(4)` passes the *integer* 4 to a function which expects a *double* parameter. (lldb does not know the prototype declaration of `tan` at that point, therefore no automatic conversion is done.) - Did you try `p (double)tan(4.0)` ? Does it produce the correct result?

Comment: Oh god, thanks ! I was focused on the return value, and not the parameter ! `call (double)tan((double)4)` and `call (double)tan(4.0)` behave as expected ! Thanks a lot